# JavaScript function "X - Y = Z" returns Y as Z value

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm trying to apply a discount to a selection in JavaScript, but for some reason, my code is returning the total to subtract as the total price:

```
  selectone = parseInt(selectone);

    var textarea = document.getElementById('discount');
    var word = '15off';
    var textValue=textarea.value;
    if (textValue.indexOf(word)!=-1)
    {
        var discval = parseFloat(selectone);
        var num = parseInt(discval);
        var retval = num - (num * .15);

    } else {
        var retval = 0
    }

  var total = selectone - retval;
  document.getElementById("rettotal").innerHTML = "Price starts from £" + total;
}
```

For example, if something costs £100 and a 15% discount is applied, the total will be '£15' instead of '£100' ('retval' instead of 'total')

Is there something I've missed in this, or is something missing? 
I've not done maths in JavaScript much so a bit over my head!

Many thanks

Comment: What is the selectOne variable?

Comment: z = x -y; might work

Comment: @RonRoyston joker (;

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use `parseInt` and `parseFloat` in your if statement since those are already numbers.  In fact, you don't even need the `discval` or `num` variables.  Just use `selectone`.

Comment: @num8er I know what `parseInt` and `parseFloat` do, and I only recommended removing the ones inside the if statement since they are redundant just like the two variables declared there.  If you look closely at the code, you'll see that `discval` is the float value parsed from `selectone` (which was already parsed to be an integer), and `num` is the integer value parsed from `discval`.  All this code is completely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because... math.

```
selectone = parseInt(selectone);
...    
var discval = parseFloat(selectone); // doesn't change the things, it's an int already
var num = parseInt(discval); // so num is essentially discval, which is selectone
var retval = num - (num * .15); // here you get 85% of num...
...
var total = selectone - retval; // here you get 15% back
```

The fix is to remove `num -` from `retval`, so as `var retval = num * .15;`

The code you've shown could be compressed to this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('discount');
var total = parseFloat(selectone)*(1-0.15*textarea.value.includes("15off"));
document.getElementById("rettotal").innerHTML = "Price starts from £" + total;
```

Or, if you have problems with `includes()` not being supported by your browser (in case it's IE), you could also use `match()`:

```
var total = parseFloat(selectone)*(1-0.15*(textarea.value.match("15off")|0));
```

Comment: You ruined the calculations !! Just return (total price - 15%) !!! see the other answer !

Comment: @Ismail I haven't ruined anything. *Just return (total price - 15%)* - that's what I suggest to do, read the last sentence. The other answer essentially mentions the same things as mine.

Comment: I'm sure that the OP will get a headache following your code :D Anyway, the answer is correct !

Comment: I actually understood this more than the top answer - either way, thank you both! It's exactly what I needed! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 3):

You've logic problem in math part.

You want to get amount after discount.

You're doing it:

```
var retval = num - (num * .15); // 100 - (100 * .15) = 85
```

But after You're removing discount from amount:

```
var total = selectone - retval; // 100 - 85 = 15
```

So here is the fix:

```
var price = parseFloat(selectone);
var discount = (textValue.indexOf('15off') != -1)? 
               price * .15 
               : 0; 
var total = price - discount; // 100 - 15 = 85
```

or just be simple (if discount applies once):

```
var total = parseFloat(selectone);
if(textValue.indexOf('15off') != -1) {
  total *= .85;
}
```

let's be flexible (applying multiple discounts to price):

```js
    var textValue = 'take this 15off and this 10off';
    var price = parseFloat(1000);
    var total = price;

        total-= (textValue.indexOf('15off') != -1)? 
                   price * .15 
                   : 0;

    console.log(total);

        total-= (textValue.indexOf('10off') != -1)? 
                   price * .15 
                   : 0;

    console.log(total);
```

Comment: Thank you num8er.  Your answer has gone over my head a little but I'm sure looking at it tomorrow after sleeping I'll get it ;) 
Many thanks for the explanation on the process too - very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have a JavaScript operator precedence and meaning problem there. That's  syntax mistake on your part.
In an expression like this:

```
    x - y = z
```

You are thinking that:

```
     z = x - y //but it's not.
```

What you are really saying is:

```
     y = z and x = x - z
```